# Expression help for Find and Replace in Notepad++ please

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

how to replace and but `symbol (,) after second number` between every five numbers by using replace in notepad++ ?

replace

```
00:00:26092 --> 00:00:30552 
00:00:36770 --> 00:00:39933 
00:00:40040 --> 00:00:42941
```

to

```
00:00:26,092 --> 00:00:30,552 
00:00:36,770 --> 00:00:39,933 
00:00:40,040 --> 00:00:42,941
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capture groups, for the "find what" field, enter `(\d{2})(\d{3})`, and for the "replace with" field enter `\1,\2`.

The parenthesis select portions of the string to capture, in this case, the first capture group selects the first two digits, then the second capture group selects next three digits. Then it replaces it with the first capture group, then a comma, then the second capture group.

[This answer on StackOverflow provides another example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414513/notepad-regex-group-capture)